# App lock for iPad Mini

Tags: ios, security

Does anyone know of an app on the Apple App Store that allows me to password lock installed apps?

The reason for this is that I will be going out of town and leaving my employee in charge of the shop. We use the iPad to charge customers on the Square App. I only want the employee to be able to access this app and restrict any usage of other installed apps such as my banking and communication apps like the built-in email app.

I can just uninstall all these information-sensitive apps but prefer not to if there is an app out there that can restrict access without a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no app that can do this. Apps installed on an IOS device are isolated and cannot control other apps. This means that password protecting entry of other apps is not possible.

If it is just one app that you would give access to someone, you may want to look into the [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612) feature and see if it is capable of locking down what you want. There is also jailbreaking your device (I DO NOT recommend this especially if you having banking apps installed) where you may be able to find an app that is capable of restricting other apps.

Comment: Ahh that make sense that Apple doesn't allow other apps to control another. Yea I definitely will no jailbreak.

Comment: @NuWin I would look into the Guided Access feature, I've used it before and it can lock you into just one app and disable the home & power button.